# Installing python bottle framework for python 3.6.1 version instead of python 2.7.1 version?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo, bottle

I am currently working on a mongo db assignment using pymongo, as part of it we need to install python bottle framework. I have installed bottle on the Mac using the below command:

```
$ pip install bottle
```

got the below message returned.

```
Requirement already satisfied: bottle in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

when I run a program from terminal which uses bottle, it throws the below error:

```
$ python hello_m101p.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hello_m101p.py", line 2, in <module>
import bottle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bottle'
```

I noted that i also have python 3.6.4 version installed on my system. I need bottle framework to be saved or installed for this version instead of the default 2.7 version. After a quick lookup around stack overflow, I tried the below command from one the suggested answers. I get the command not found error:

```
sudo pip-3.6.4 install bottle

sudo: pip-3.6.4: command not found
```

Any help to correct this error ? I am not sure how to address this. Please let me know if the question is unclear or need more context.

Comment: The `pip` command that you want should be called `pip3.6` (and also `pip3`), not `pip-3.6.4`. That's why you get a `command not found`.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert    'sudo pip3 ' install bottle worked instead of pip3.6. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default name for `pip` for Python version X.Y.Z is not `pip-X.Y.Z`, but `pipX.Y`. Some linux distros use different names for their versions, but I believe on Mac, both the python.org Python installer and the Homebrew python package (and you probably have one of those two) use the default names, at least as of 2018.

If you only have one `3.Y.Z`, it will probably also be available as `pip3`, which is convenient.

If you've got different names and are hopelessly confused, but you do know how to run your Python 3 itself, you can always use the `-m` flag to run `pip`.

Also, most Mac Python installs don't need `sudo`. If you don't know whether you do, try it without first. If you get a bunch of permissions errors, then you do need `sudo` after all, but otherwise, don't use it.

So, what you want is probably any of these:

```
pip3.6 install bottle
pip3 install bottle
python3 -m pip install bottle
```